# PHP create .deb packages from source

Tags: php

I am try now to compile and create PHP 7.1.7 (.deb)-packages with Debian 8  from source.

I had downloaded PHP 7.1.7.

Extract, after it execute ./configure afterwards I make follow command
"make test". I don't know why I get every time Errors in my Console like  that:

=====================================================================

TIME END 2017-08-02 15:05:48

=====================================================================

### TEST RESULT SUMMARY

Exts skipped    :   48

### Exts tested     :   26

Number of tests : 15404             10283
Tests skipped   : 5121 ( 33.2%) --------
Tests warned    :    0 (  0.0%) (  0.0%)
Tests failed    :    4 (  0.0%) (  0.0%)
Expected fail   :   35 (  0.2%) (  0.3%)

### Tests passed    : 10244 ( 66.5%) ( 99.6%)

## Time taken      :  401 seconds

=====================================================================

### EXPECTED FAILED TEST SUMMARY

Test open_basedir configuration [tests/security/open_basedir_linkinfo.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: BUG: open_basedir cannot delete symlink to prohibited file. See also
bugs 48111 and 52176.
Inconsistencies when accessing protected members [Zend/tests/access_modifiers_008.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Discussion: http://marc.info/?l=php-internals&m=120221184420957&w=2
Inconsistencies when accessing protected members - 2

...

Phar: bug #69958: Segfault in Phar::convertToData on invalid file [ext/phar/tests/bug69958.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Still has memory leaks, see https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=70005
updateTimestamp never called when session data is empty [ext/session/tests/bug71162.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Current session module is designed to write empty session always. In addition, current session module only supports SessionHandlerInterface only from PHP 7.0.
Bug #70219 Use after free vulnerability in session deserializer [ext/standard/tests/serialize/bug70219.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: Unfinished merge, needs fix.

## Bug #70470 (Built-in server truncates headers spanning over TCP packets) [sapi/cli/tests/bug70470.phpt]  XFAIL REASON: bug is not fixed yet

=====================================================================

### FAILED TEST SUMMARY

Test for DateTime::modify() with absolute time statements [ext/date/tests/date-time-modify-times.phpt]
Bug #69900 Commandline input/output weird behaviour with STDIO [ext/standard/tests/streams/proc_open_bug69900.phpt]
Bug #70436: Use After Free Vulnerability in unserialize() [ext/standard/tests/strings/bug70436.phpt]

## Bug #72663: Create an Unexpected Object and Don't Invoke __wakeup() in Deserialization [ext/standard/tests/strings/bug72663_3.phpt]

What I do wrong?

Comment: Why do you want to compile it from source? There are deb packages already available if you just need PHP 7.1

Comment: I would like to learn, create my own packages for myself.

Comment: OK, fair enough. If you just want the latest version, [Ondrej Sury's PPA is the place to go](https://deb.sury.org/).